# Why should I define JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme for my Authorize attribute always?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity

I have a simple sample for JWT Authentication which you can find it [here](https://github.com/HamedFathi/JwtTokenSample)

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
```

As you can see I have added `JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` to the `Authentication` inside `Startup/ConfigureServices` method so I should be able to use the `[Authorize]` **standalone** as following

```cs
[Authorize]
public sealed class WeatherForecastController : BaseController
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };
```

but I dont know why it does not work! (I have tested with Postman). I **must** define it via `AuthenticationSchemes`.

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public sealed class WeatherForecastController : BaseController
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };
```

Can any one guide me how can I use `Authorize` attribute standalone **without** `AuthenticationSchemes` especially when I have defined it inside `ConfigureServices`? What did I set wrong?

Comment: I think u should 1: services.AddAuthorization() in the ConfigureServices method, and than 2: app.UseAuthorization() in Configure method, in order to use the authorization features from ASP.Net, after that you should have Authorization without specifying the scheme

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code does not have `app.UseAuthentication()` included. So that means there is no authentication middleware.

The default authentication scheme is used only by the authentication middleware to auto-authenticate the request and build-up the current principal. When you use `[Authorize]` alone, the authentication schemes are not set and the authorization filters will not work. The filter built from that `IAuthorizeData` (`AuthorizeAttribute` is an `IAuthorizeData`) is an `AuthorizeFilter` and this requires the schemes to be set explicitly.

That's why the other `[Authorize(...)]` with some scheme set works but not the `[Authorize]`.

So you should use the authentication middleware to use `[Authorize]` conveniently without having to specify the schemes.

The `AuthorizeFilter` will use `IPolicyEvaluator` internally to authenticate the request, here's the default implementation of [PolicyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/62b77d0bad02e72b6675545392ecb3232d508e43/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/PolicyEvaluator.cs#L36) - you can see it checks for the availability of `AuthenticationSchemes`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also configure the `FallbackPolicy` which will be used by the authorization middleware if no other policy or requirement has been specified for an endpoint.

Comment: Forcing the `AuthenticationSchemes` property on the `AuthorizeAttribute` masked the issue that I had an extra `app.UseAuthorization()` above the `app.UseAuthentication()` call. Removing this removed the need to explicitly set `AuthenticationSchemes`.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 5, you can config as below:

Add **JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme** as default scheme string in **AddJwtBearer**

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, jwt =>
       {
         jwt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
           {
             ValidateIssuer = true,
                       ....
            ;
                
         });
```

Use in Configure (in case using Role as well)

```
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
```

And then you can use [Authorired] Attribute as default

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/data")]
[Authorize]
public class DataController : ControllerBase
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a conflict between AddIdentityCore() and AddIdentity() methods. If you use AddIdentity, it uses Cookie based authentication so JWT doesnt work if you dont write [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] explicitly. I changed my startup as below and now it works with [Authorize] in .Net 6. I am using custom classes for both user and role.

```
services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(x =>
{
    x.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    x.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
    x.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    x.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    x.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
})
.AddRoles<AppRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DBContext>();
```